# asp image button click event with JQuery Mobile

Tags: vb.net, jquery-mobile

I have been working on a site in VB.NET and JQM - and all has been going OK.

Now, I am trying to include a standard Image button using a tag such as:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnYear" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/year_btn.gif" />
```

and in the VB code behind file there is a click event similar to the following:

```
Private Sub btnYear_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnYear.Click    
    Session("TimeFrame") = "YEAR"    
    *do other code* 
End Sub
```

When I click the Image Button and trace the code - all the code in the page events in the code behind file fire (page load, page prerender, etc) - but the click event for the image button never fires.

If I replace the Image button with a standard asp:Button and do all the same - then the click event in the code behind fires just fine!  Is it not possible to use an ASP ImageButton within a JQM page and hold a click event in the VB Code behind file?

**EDIT**
Ok much appreciation to andleer for his response - but it brings a new scenario (problem) with my page to light, also concerning these ImageButtons.

I have the ImageButton controls contained within a user control.  My page is a single ASPX file with multiple
`<div data-role="page">`
elemenst in it, each with its own ID ("page1", "page2", "page3", etc) - following the standard usage of JQM's multi-page functionality.  Each "page" section contains an instance of the user control that contains the Image buttons.  This all works well, with one problem - when the user navigates away from the default "page1" to any other "page" and clicks one of the image buttons, the code fires, the page reloads - and lands the user back on the default page - "page1".

This is no good - I needed a way to allow the user to fire the button and reload the page and stay on the "page" element they were viewing - JQM accomplishes these multiple pages using hash tags in the URL - so I found a line of code that I added to the page's load event which read:

`Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    Me.Form.Attributes("onsubmit") = "this.action+=top.location.hash;"

End Sub`
```

I was originally using radio buttons on my user control - which JQM was "skinning" so they appeard as buttons - and with this one line in the Page_Load event, a user could click a radio button on any "page" element and the code behind the radio buttons would fire and the page would reload with the user back on the same "page" element they clicked from - not so replacing the radio button with Image Buttons - when I add that line of code to the Page_Load event, the ImageButton controls completely cease to function - when I click the the code in their click even in the code behind does not fire - nor do any of the page level events such as Page_Load or Page_PreRender - clicking them now does absolutely nothing....

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

A new answer to address the second part of your question:

I have found that asp.net web forms simply doesn't work with jQuery Mobile multi page scenarios. Web forms requires all web controls to reside within a single `<form />` element that needs to span all jQuery Mobile ("virtual") pages. This is in direct conflict with jQuery Mobile's need to have `<form />` elements within each sub page for proper rendering and post packs.

Consider MVC instead.

Comment: Unfortunately switching to MVC at this point is out of the question :/  This post-back issue redirecting to the incorrect "page" element of a multipage document is one of the last issues to resolve before we present this - and it needs to be presented within the week!  With the entire thing working in Web Forms - and my own knowledge base being in web forms - I must find a way to make this happen here - I would love to look into MVC down the road though....

Comment: I spent a large amount of time trying to get a jqm multi-page template  working within asp.net web forms and eventually gave up on the idea. The form element issue that I described above cannot be overcome. The same issue occurs with any ajax enabled DOM loading. Your only hope to get this working within asp.net web forms it to turn off all ajax loading to go with single page templates.

I could be wrong but I was not able to overcome this issue / limitation.

Comment: I appreciate all your help!  I did manage to get something working using a hidden field that javascript loaded with the pages hash tag on button click, and then a javascript that appended that back on to the url when loading - but it just seemed like a "hoaky" solution that may lead to trouble later - so I am working on single page pages now to see if I can get that to work better.

Comment: I think that asp.net web forms and jquery mobile can be made to work and potentially work well if you limit yourself to single page templates and disable all of the ajax loading so you don't build multi-page DOM scenarios. So long as your clients are connecting locally via WiFi, you are likely OK. If you expect to reach 3G/4G clients with this, you will have major performance issues.

Comment: The single page scenario hit some snags (the biggest one being an inability to use JQM transitions from page to page which the user really wants...) - I am back to a multi-page layout.  I have a javascript routine that store the hash tag in a hidden field, and the page appends the hashtag from that hidden field via another javascript.  The image buttons are calling the javascript routine to store the hashtag into the hidden variable first - then they execuet their click event in the code behind.  It is working for now - but I will have to see how it holds up to more thorough testing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that an `<asp:ImageButton />` renders as a `<input type="image" />` which is hidden by jQuery Mobile. Add a data-role="none" to you ImageButton which will cause jQuery Mobile to render the control as is.

```
<asp:ImageButton id="MyButton" runat="server" data-role="none" />
```

Comment: I appreciate your response - I have a bit of a different twist that I will post in a reply - as it is a bit too lengthy for a comment....